# Multiple sub-workspaces in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I write code in several languages (Python, C, C++, and Java) using Eclipse. Is it possible to designate a directory on my machine (say /home/workspace/) as the "primary" workspace for any Eclipse session, but then to have subfolders, /home/workspace/python, /home/workspace/java, etc., in which I can create new Eclipse projects.

I don't want to have to navigate menus and select different workspaces for each session of Eclipse that I start up. I would rather just always have permission to manipulate any projects from a variety of folders at any time, but I can't find a clear answer about whether this can be done and how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question; You want to have one workspace, but be able to code in several different languages without switching workspace but at the same time keep the projects separated?

First I would suggest you consider several workspaces, I find it convenient to keep settings and projects in separate workspaces. I rarely have to switch language that often.

But. I think what you want to do is to keep several working sets. You create one java working set, one C++ set and associate your different projects with a working set. Then you can minimize the java working set when you are running C++. For working sets you dont need any subfolders on the harddrive.

You might also want to look into [Mylyn](http://eclipse.org/mylyn/). Its a great tool for those who often are switching context. It saves the context (eclipse perspective, open files, etc) as associated with a task.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting Eclipse to prompt for the workspace at launch?  It wouldn't allow you to work in two languages at once, but should do the trick otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

An Eclipse workspace can contain projects slated for different languages and those projects can live anywhere on your hard drive. There are at least two ways to do what you want. When creating a new project, uncheck the `Use default location` checkbox and browse to or specify the folder where you want your project to live. If a project already exists import the project into the workspace using the `File->Import` menu option and then select `Existing Projects into workspace`. In the next screen make sure the checkbox for `Copy projects into workspace` is not selected. This will leave the source files in the original folder.

In the Project explorer view, all the projects are going to look like they live at the root level. However you can group related projects into working sets. Then select just the working set you're interested in and all the others will disappear from view.

A warning is in order if you make use of [eclipse variables in external tools](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/concepts-exttools.htm?cp=0_2_10_1) (and possibly elsewhere). The syntax you use for paths needs to be adjusted. For example with projects outside the workspace this syntax  `${workspace_loc:/MyProject/MyFile.txt}` is no longer the same as this syntax `${workspace_loc}/MyProject/MyFile.txt`